# How To Get Selenium to Click Sign In Button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to get selenium to log in to a page to scrape data. I can't get it to click the "Sign in" button.  Inspecting the button HTML gives me:

```
<button class="btn__primary--large from__button--floating" data-litms-control-urn="login-submit" type="submit" aria-label="Sign in">Sign in</button>
```

The online documentation for selenium has been very unhelpful. Does anyone know what I would use to have selenium identify and click the button? The latest unsuccessful try I executed was:

```
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "Sign in").click()
```

Link to page: https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2Fmy-items%2Fsaved-jobs%2F%3Fstart%3D0&fromSignIn=true&trk=cold_join_sign_in

Comment: Please share a link to that page

Comment: @Prophet updated w/link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following CSS_Selector:

```py
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']").click()
```

Don't forget to wait for the element to become clickable.
This should be done with use of `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions`
As following

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login?session_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fwww%2Elinkedin%2Ecom%2Fmy-items%2Fsaved-jobs%2F%3Fstart%3D0&fromSignIn=true&trk=cold_join_sign_in"

wait_5 = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

wait_5.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/main/div[3]/div[1]/form/div[3]/button'))).click()
```

It would be better to use selenium-wire undetected browser with proxies!)